# Dissable_keyGuard flag not working

Tags: android, locking, screen-lock

I'm trying to disable screen lock. I want the screen to go off after timeout, but to go on again with my app when touched.

Since keywardlock is deprecated, I tried the following in onCreate():

```
    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Just in  case, I added the following in the manifest (is this needed??):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED" />
```

Still, after my usual timeout, the screen is locked...

What am I doing wrong??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[SetFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags%28int,%20int%29) takes the flags and a mask you are not using it that way.  The easyest thing is to use the helper method [addFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#addFlags%28int%29) I am using the following code.

```
  Window window = getWindow();
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong, thanks. However, your suggestion only works partially. While I don't need a gesture to unlock the screen with your suggestion, I still need to press the middle bottom button of the phone. I tried adding FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, but then the screen does not turns off at all. I want the screen to turn off, but to wake up when touching it (not the middle bottom button). Maybe this is not possible...?

Comment: I don't belive that's possible.  The touch sensor is only powered up when the screen is powered up.  I have to hit a hard button to wake things up but I then go straight back to my app.  if you do find out how to do it I would like to know....

Comment: I understand. Related to this is the partial wakelock. I was not able to make it work on a Galaxy Note (ICS), only full wakelock seems to work.